# Microsoft Entra - Attribute Assignment Administrator cannot see Custom Security Attributes for any user

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-entra-id

In Microsoft Entra my member user with the Attribute Assignment Administrator role cannot see Custom Security Attributes for any user.

Following this Microsoft documentation for [Custom Security Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/users/users-custom-security-attributes?tabs=ms-powershell) I should be able to then navigate to a user and assign a custom security attribute and value to that user. However, I cannot even see the option that is clearly shown of the screenshots of the tutorial. Am I missing something?

[image]

I tried granting my user the Attribute Assignment Administrator, Global Administration, User Administrator, and Attribute Definition Administrator roles. The tutorial shows the Custom Security Attributes should show like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Initially*, I faced the same issue:

[image]

> **Note** that: The user must have **`Attribute Assignment Administrator`** active role assigned to access custom security attributes.

Make sure to assign Active role:

[image]

[image]

***I am able to add the Custom Security Attributes successfully:***

[image]

**If still the issue persists**, Login to [**Microsoft Entra Admin Center**](https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?redirect_uri=https://entra.microsoft.com/signin/index/&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=https://management.core.windows.net//user_impersonation%20openid%20email%20profile&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties=iuEBmyAslvkSBGjbam-wKs0Uy0VghS6Dgv2I7tKRziNk3uWGUumoXFgqTOF1BI874sjU1LqouFqjwX-6ezUCdxpWjqFHFjHMdzj5qeThdUwJXgE93YKhMbQJfhaVOSdEK65_ASBxJzp8hC-xoozgrNI3b5P0YNVQMYODUSLRMwPtWQrg6c3DeEXbwIMpovOMdOoih1nL0SDJ4g4OwBdpbHRt1RzC-Cdeg-qvv_EMXQU7UYv95TPRQFxSmUaingak2ehwvIFB6_XLBQ4uB4Iu2GDUvOQgJU69V0rUkQFw-qVuawnro1ikhhuhoPzqzqKi89BCrycu-gfm8n9mEZMaVE3RsZckMioLSDTWUdp-QYsCKPWGh0muRnN4LfpKIVLII-ds4cWaSSxASVeroBOzicwIp2FcJcoegJwOrp3KdsqHFKpOelkUFE13L7xthxggGU7THKK0-TZr6PyEBtPG1d0EBKNO6JHvzVNieD6pm4Y&response_mode=form_post&nonce=638388328818180350.YzJmYTgwMjQtNzU4OC00Zjg2LTgxNjItYWZlMzMxNjQxM2FlMzg5MWNlZWMtN2FiYy00MDNjLWIyMjMtZmE3Y2MxMTliODc4&client_id=c44b4083-3bb0-49c1-b47d-974e53cbdf3c&site_id=501430&cobrandid=106b89c7-ab4e-4963-afb3-004cd2f15cac&client-request-id=89b52d15-4b3d-4309-a209-09884b60875f&x-client-SKU=ID_NET472&x-client-ver=6.30.1.0&sso_nonce=AwABAAEAAAACAOz_BQD0_0fE6nQ4KV00ptDilQmP2gc5ugb2ohepXj6J1WVhT5hxbfVILkUldoz9XszS-UE9G-FTIoQ4TS9VWH4jbbYziZYgAA&mscrid=89b52d15-4b3d-4309-a209-09884b60875f) and add the custom security attribute:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. It looks like you are using Privileged Identity Management which is a premium feature. I'm using the free version of Microsft Entra. I don't have an option to make a role assignment active or inactive, just to assign the role. However, I can create custom security attributes with the "Attribute Definition Administrator" role. So that role assignment appears to be working without needing to activate.

Comment: AFAIK you need an active assignment to access custom security attributes

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been fixed. Now the Custom Security Attributes show correctly when looking at a user while having the "Attribute Assignment Administrator" role.